# How do I make a variable global across a Java file

Tags: java, variables, global-variables

In lua I could just do `global variablename` and bam its global
is there a simple way to do this in java?

Here is my code, I want the `loc` variable to be global so the `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){` can use it:

> ```
> class custom_row_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
>       custom_row_adapter(Context context, int picId, String url) {
>         super(context, R.layout.activity_custom_row_adapter, picId);
>         String loc = url;
> }
> @Override
> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
>         LayoutInflater picInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
>         View customView = picInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_row_adapter, parent, false);
>         String singlePic = getItem(loc + String.valueOf(position) + ".jpg"); **//this is where loc is viewed**
>         ImageView theImage = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.singleImg);
>         Glide.with(this).load(singlePic).into(theImage);
>         return customView;
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: In this case you would need to make it `public static String loc` i believe but you need to put it after the line `class custom_row .....` and the to access it you need to do `custom_row_adapter.loc`

Comment: There is no such thing as a global variable scope in java as far as language goes (there is no global namespace for variables). But you can refer to any public static member by fully qualifying the reference (e.g. MyClass.myStaticPublicField)

Comment: @3kings it worked! Post it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add it as and field like this

```
public class example {

private String loc;

class custom_row_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
    custom_row_adapter(Context context, int picId, String url) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_custom_row_adapter, picId);
        loc = url;
    }
  }
}
```